# Get a property's value using reflection

Tags: intersystems-cache

Let's say I have several classes that extend from MyAbstractClass each containing their own properties that do not exist on MyAbstractClass.  How would I get a property value from one of those classes?

Something like this: (pseudocode)

```
Method GetPropertyValue(myAbstractClass As MyAbstractClass) As %String 
{
  Set myPropertyValue = myAbstractClass.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty").GetValue();
  Quit myPropertyValue
}
```

So far I have this:

```
Method GetPropertyValue(argBusinessObject As BusinessObject)
{
    // get class name. 
    set className = argBusinessObject.%PackageName()_"."_argBusinessObject.%ClassName()

    set dictionary = ##class(%Dictionary.ClassDefinition).%OpenId(className)
    if (dictionary '= "")
    {
        for index=1:1:dictionary.Properties.Count()
        {
            #dim clsPropDef As %Dictionary.PropertyDefinition
            // Get the property name from the class
            set clsPropDef = dictionary.Properties.GetAt(index)

            if (..PropertyName = clsPropDef.Name) {             
                // we have the property
                // Set the propName so that it gets included
                // now what?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Method GetPropertyValue(PropertyName)
{
  Q $PROPERTY(##this,Name)
}
```

In [older versions](http://training.intersystems.com/tutorials/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCNV_R2010_1) of Cache you would use $ZOBJPROPERTY instead of $PROPERTY.  Apparently prior to version 2010.1.

Comment: that does not compile for me.

Comment: Oops, fixed.  Sorry, called away before I could check it.

Comment: This is not available in my version of cache.  I had to use $ZOBJPROPERTY

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast types in Cache.

If you need to get a known property, you may use usual syntax:

```
Set myPropertyValue = myAbstractClass.MyProperty
```

If you need to get a property which is not known, you may use $property function

```
Set myPropertyName = "PropertyNumber"_i
Set myPropertyValue = $property(myAbstractClass,myPropertyName)
```